# Azure AD B2C Custom policy, how to put application scopes in access token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Here's the configuration for the Azure AD B2C, create two applications: web and api. added two scopes read and write to the api scope. configure web application to web application. tested with the built-in user flows e.g. sign up sign in. run the flow for the web app, get the access token, scopes are in the token.

now create a custom policy to use multitenants to authenticate the users with Azure AD. created a custom signup/in policy. run the policy, got the access token by specifying the api scopes in the access token, however the return token does not contain the scope claims. my question is how to configure the custom policy to have the api scopes in the access token?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the custom policy, it will only return an ID token rather than access token.

So your scope claims won't be included in the ID token.

You should refer to [Request an access token in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens).

After you have [Added a web API application to your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application?tabs=applications), use authorization code flow to get the access token.

```
GET https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<application-ID>
&nonce=anyRandomValue
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https://<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read
&response_type=code
```

The response with the authorization code should be similar to this example:

```
https://jwt.ms/?code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMC...
```

After successfully receiving the authorization code, you can use it to request an access token:

```
POST <tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=<policy-name> HTTP/1.1
Host: <tenant-name>.b2clogin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=<application-ID>
&scope=https://<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read
&code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMC...
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&client_secret=2hMG2-_:y12n10vwH...
```

The response:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrN...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1549647431,
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "expires_on": 1549651031,
    "resource": "f2a76e08-93f2-4350-833c-965c02483b11",
    "profile_info": "eyJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAiLCJ0aWQiOiJjNjRhNGY3ZC0zMDkxLTRjNzMtYTcyMi1hM2YwNjk0Z..."
}
```

See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#request-a-token).

Comment: used the test UI in Azure portal for B2C. got the token back e.g. with https://jwt.ms. it's the access_token but the scp claims are not there. so i wonder if my custom policy for relying party needs to add the outputclaims for scp specifically.

Comment: never mind, it's the portal test UI not showing the scopes in the claims, works fine with the code in the application.